# Problema Laravel 5.2 non-object no foreach

Tags: php, laravel, relacionamento, laravel-5.2

Estou tentando puxar as informações deste relacionamento como podem ver abaixo:

Modelo:

```
public function endereco(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\End\Logradouro_Bairro');
}

public function local(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Admin\Local');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function indexLocal()
 {
    $local = Local::all();
    $secretaria = UnidadeOrganizacional::all();
    $endereco = Logradouro_Bairro::all();
    return view('admin.local')->with('local',$local)->with('secretaria',$secretaria)->with('endereco',$endereco);
 }
```

View

```
@foreach($endereco as $loc)
                          <tr data-id="{{ $loc->id }}" data-sec="{{ $loc->secretaria_id }}">
                            <td>{{ $loc->secretaria->sigla }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $loc->nomeDoLocal }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $loc->endereco->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $loc->telefone }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $loc->telefone2 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $loc->telefone3 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $loc->telefone4 }}</td>
                            <td><i class="material-icons editar md-color-cyan-700" style="font-size:16px; cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5">&#xE150;</i></td>
                            <td><i class="deletar fa fa-times md-color-red-400" style="font-size:16px; cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal6"></i></td>
                          </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

Erro:

> ```
> Trying to get property of non-object in 13cbbd34b07174638fff7aab751ea42a1099d2cf.php line 121
> at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\laragon\www\feed\storage\framework\views\13cbbd34b07174638fff7aab751ea42a1099d2cf.php', '121', array('__path' => 'C:\laragon\www\feed\storage\framework\views/13cbbd34b07174638fff7aab751ea42a1099d2cf.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'local' => object(Collection), 'secretaria' => object(Collection), 'endereco' => object(Collection)), 'obLevel' => '1', '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'local' => object(Collection), 'secretaria' => object(Collection), 'endereco' => object(Collection), 'sec' => object(UnidadeOrganizacional), 'end' => object(Logradouro_Bairro), 'loc' => object(Logradouro_Bairro))) in 13cbbd34b07174638fff7aab751ea42a1099d2cf.php line 121
> at include('C:\laragon\www\feed\storage\framework\views\13cbbd34b07174638fff7aab751ea42a1099d2cf.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
> at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\laragon\www\feed\storage\framework\views/13cbbd34b07174638fff7aab751ea42a1099d2cf.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'local' => object(Collection), 'secretaria' => object(Collection), 'endereco' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
> at CompilerEngine->get('C:\laragon\www\feed\resources\views/admin/local.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'local' => object(Collection), 'secretaria' => object(Collection), 'endereco' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 149
> ```

Este erro é apresentado sempre que tento acessar o relacionamento, ele funciona se eu utilizar como array:

```
{{ $loc->enderero['id'] }}
```

Porem isso não ajuda pois estou pegando o id apenas como teste, na verdade eu preciso ir mais fundo neste relacionamento:

```
{{ $loc->endereco->logradouro->nome }}
```

Alguém já teve este tipo de problema? Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Se você usar `{{ $loc->enderero['logradouro']['nome'] }}` não vai funcionar?

Comment: `enderero` esta correto?

Comment: Coloque os 3 modelos na sua pergunta...

Answer (score 1):

Opa, pelo que notei a questão está sendo no Controller...vc não esta chamando as relações, apenas chamando cada Modelo separadamente...

No caso era para vc chamar dessa forma..

//Controller.

**$secretaria = UnidadeOrganizacional::with('endereco', 'local')->get();**

vc ta informando que unidade tem relação com endereço e local...

Veja o link abaixo que vc vai entender melhor...

Ps. Se os atributos de relacionamento não tiver de acordo com os padrões do Laravel vc terá que informar as chaves de relacionamento nos metodos (endereco e local);

ex:

```
public function endereco(){
  return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Admin\Local', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

Link: http://magazine.softerize.com.br/tutoriais/php/laravel/relacionamento-entre-tabelas-laravel